# If $f$ is a real valued function, complex differentiable at $z_0$, then $f'(z_0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Cannot understand this proof that a real-valued function which is complex differentiable must have derivative at that point equal to zero. I just don't understand how the last statement in bold is validated.

> If $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ then there exists a complex number $\xi_0$ such that $$\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \rightarrow \xi_0\;\; \text{as} \;\; (z-z_0)\rightarrow 0$$
>   Let $\text{Re}(z-z_0)=s$ and $\text{Im}(z-z_0)=t$, so that $s+it=z-z_0$. Then taking $t=0$ and letting $s\rightarrow 0$ we have that $$\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{s} \rightarrow \xi_0\;\; \text{as} \;\; s\rightarrow 0$$ Since $f$ is real valued then we have that Im($\xi_0)=0$. Now taking $s=0$ and letting $t\rightarrow 0$ we have $$\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{it} \rightarrow \xi_0\;\; \text{as} \;\; t\rightarrow 0$$
>   $\textbf{Which implies that Re($\xi_0$)=0.}$

Comment: Same as above. The reason is again that $f$ is real-valued. The expression on the left is purely imaginary for any $t$. So, $\xi_0$ must be purely imaginary, which means $\operatorname{Re}(\xi_0) = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is real valued and $t$ is a real number,
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{t}
$$
is a real number. Then
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{i\,t}=-i\,\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{t}
$$
has real part equal to $0$. The same is then true of its limit.